# Adding Data on a Daily basis in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

There are two tables, the DADOS_ANTIGOS table and the DADOS_DIARIOS table.

The DADOS_ANTIGOS table has data from previous years.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0ubH.png)

The DADOS_DIARIOS table only has data from the current day, and when data from the next day arrives, the entire DADOS_DIARIOS table is changed with the values ​​and date of the day that arrived and so on.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkojI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhLKr.png)
Data source of the DADOS_DIARIOS table

However, when I change the data source of the DADOS_DIARIOS table to data from November 24th:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqS4c.png)

When merging the DADOS_OLD table with DADOS_DIARIOS in Power BI, it does not save the DADOS_DIARIOS data before it is changed, it simply replaces it.
Before:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22TkZ.png)

After:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2zwI.png)

Note that the data from November 23rd was changed to the 24th. I need it to keep the data from the 23rd and then add the data from the 24th and the other days successively.

In short, I need a method that adds the DAILY_DATA to the DADOS_ANTIGOS table, so that it saves the data from the DAILY_DATA table that was changed the previous day and so on.

ALERT: I cannot add new rows to the DADOS_DIARIOS data source, as the API I use in the main project changes all the current day's data daily.

Comment: You mention `DADOS_ANTIGOS` only has previous years data in it. When will new dates appear in `DADOS_ANTIGOS`? Are you expected to persist the daily table, each day for a year? Seems like a gap in the API design.

Comment: As Sam indicates in his answer, you'll need some sort of database, then use incremental load, or a file store, but that will load all the data every time its refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Power BI does not persist data. During refresh, it gets all the data again, so the behaviour your experiencing is as expected.

You will need to persist the daily data yourself via other means and then pull this into Power BI.

Comment: Do you know of any way to record the data so I can put it in Power BI later?

Comment: Will you have to do this daily for a year? When will new dates come into `DADOS_ANTIGOS`?

Comment: The idea is to supply DADOS_OLD with daily data from the DADOS_DIARIOS table. This supply would happen daily for an indefinite period of time, but probably for a year.

Comment: Approximately, how many rows per day, and roughly for the year? Do you have Power BI Data Mart? Do you have an Azure Subscription? Do you have a database team? There are so many options for this task.